# Frameworks for automated android malware

Tags: android, frameworks, import, detection, malware

I am currently doing a malware detection program for android, however as it is not required to start from scratch, I was recommended to use a framework. But I am unsure of how to import the framework into the program. Are there any specific programming language which allows importing of framework or does all programming language allow importing?

Comment: which framework you are using?

Comment: q is rather vague.  you'll be using 'java' (dalvyk) on  android.  framework will likely have source.

Comment: Hi thanks for the help I will check out java(dalvyk). @Shivaji I am still currently searching for a suitable framework as i am not intending to create a phone app but a  computer program instead. (Not sure if android frameworks can be used)

Answer (score -1):

In my experience I have always used Spring Android when developing. You can give it a shot! :)